# How do I direct Quarkus hibernate sql log to a separate file handler

Tags: sql, hibernate, logging, quarkus

I have this in my application.properties.  the sql file created, but nothing goes into it, and everything still is showing in console.

```
quarkus.log.handler.console."SqlConsoleHandler".enable=true
quarkus.log.handler.file."SqlFileHandler".enable=true
quarkus.log.handler.file."SqlFileHandler".path=hibernate.sql
quarkus.log.handler.file."SqlFileHandler".rotation.max-file-size=500M
quarkus.log.handler.file."SqlFileHandler".rotation.max-backup-index=200
quarkus.log.handler.file."SqlFileHandler".rotation.file-suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm
quarkus.log.handler.file."SqlFileHandler".rotation.rotate-on-boot=true
quarkus.log.category."hibernate".use-parent-handlers=false
quarkus.log.category."hibernate".level=DEBUG
quarkus.log.category."hibernate".handlers=SqlConsoleHandler,SqlFileHandler
quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=true
quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.bind-param=true
```

Answer (score 1):

My bet would be that `hibernate` is not the correct category. You need to use the full category of the log.

Have you tried with `org.hibernate`? It will redirect all the Hibernate logs though.

Apparently, `org.hibernate.SQL` is what you look like for only pushing the SQL statements to a specific file.

This article might be useful: https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-logging-guide/ .

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked fine.  I also added the category "org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" to get the bind param values, not sure if that is working full.  NOW IF ONLY I could get the Quarkus logging to do the rotate on size correctly!

Comment: I remember having seen an issue in our tracker about this. Was it you? If not could you open an issue describing the problem and how to reproduce it? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it was me.  Sorry, but a little "disgruntled" with that topic.  The only reply I could get was "well it works fine in our two line test cases!".  So for instance, with this most recent change, almost every SQL statement comes out in a separate file.  I rarely see a file greater than 10k in size.  I really need it fixed, but I just keep updating to the later versions of Quarkus with the hope that one day it will work correctly.  I know there is a newer version available now, I just need time in our program schedule to change to it.